# React Redux - Issue passing props

Tags: reactjs, redux

On one screen (named LCL_Active) I display a list of users. Once a user is selected, the user's information (being passed as props) will be displayed on the next screen (named LCL_Active_Details).  The action I've created that does this is (LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment).  My Reducer is called (items). 
Currently, when I click on one of the users, the information is not displaying on the next screen.  But, as you can see in my reducer I have a console.log command that captures the user being clicked... this console.log works and is capturing the information. However, when attempting to pass in these props to LCL_Active_Details no prop information is being displayed

REDUCER (items):

```
export function items(state = [], action) {
switch (action.type) {
case 'ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
    return action.payload;
case 'FETCH_USERS_SELECTED':
    return action.payload;
default:
    return state;
```

}
}

ACTION (LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment):

```
export const LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment = (item) => {
    const action = {
        type: FETCH_USERS_SELECTED, 
        payload: item
    }
    console.log("You clicked on user:", item.name);
    return action

    };
```

SCREEN THAT DISPLAYS LIST OF USERS AND IDENTIFIES WHICH USER WAS CLICK:

```
 class LCL_Active extends Component {
 import LCLActiveList from "../../../components/detailsLayout";

   componentDidMount() {
 this.props.fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');

            } 
            render() {

            return (
                <Container> 
                        <Header style={styles.MainContainer} hasTabs>                    
                                <Body>
                                    <Title>LCL</Title>
                                </Body>
                            <Right />
                        </Header>

     <Content padder>
    <LCLActiveList items={this.props.items} 
    LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment{this.props.LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment} 
    navigation {this.props.navigation}/>
                        </Content>
                    </Container>
                );
            }
        }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {              
         LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment:state.LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment,
            items: state.items,
          };
        }

        function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url)),
            LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment: (item) => 
            dispatch(LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment(item))

           }
         }
        export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps
        (LCL_Active);
```

SCREEN TO DISPLAY SELECTED USERS:

```
 class LCL_Active_Details extends Component {
 import { DetailsLayout } from "../../../components/detailsLayout";

 render() {      
  return (
  <Container>
    <Content padder>
      <Text style={styles.header_2}>ROUTING</Text>
        <DetailsLayout item={this.props.items} /> 
    </Content>
  </Container>
  );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  items: state.items 
 };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
 return {
  LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment(item) {
        debugger;
        dispatch(LCL_ActiveSelectedShipment(item))
  }
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps 
(LCL_Active_Details);
```

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Hello Colin. Not sure how to use the site you provided.  I've created a repo.  Hope this helps https://github.com/psychatelli/Redux_Issue

Comment: Also, just a heads up... the code in this post is filtered down compared to what you will see inside each file within the repo.  The component files to look for [components >lcl_shipment_components>lcl_active_list.js ].  Also tab_components>detailsLayout.js.  Screens are [screens>LCL>active.js].  And [screens>ShipmentActive>details.js]. The action is in [actions>shipment_actions.js]. Reducer is in the [recuers>lcl> LCL_new.js]

Comment: You can just drag and drop those files into the link I gave you.

Comment: Oh, nice.  Ok, I added the file (I called it TE).  I'll work on that platform you provided to get the screen to display.  For now, here is the current link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3479v1?file=index.js

Comment: Not all files get transfered over to stackblitz.com.

Comment: I don't see anything there.

Comment: The site doesn't save my content.  Are you able to download the files from GitHub here https://github.com/psychatelli/Redux_Issue ?